# Return an Exception Instead of Throwing

Tags: python, error-handling, monads

I have a set of calling functions (bar() in the below example) that do not behave well when exceptions are raised (running tasks in parallel with Celery). I would therefore prefer to catch all exceptions and then return them. My code below demonstrates the desired behavior, however, I find it rather verbose and delicate. Is there a better option available to emulate this behavior? Performance is not an issue.

```
class V():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.value = x

class E():
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.error = e

def foo(a,b,c):
    try:
        return V(error_prone_function(a,b,c))
    except Exception as e:
        return E(e)

def bar():
    result = foo(1,2,3)
    if isinstance(result, V):
        do_success(result.value)
    else:
        do_failure(result.error)
```

EDIT: I would ideally like to have a generalized version of foo(). Something like:

```
def bar():
    result, error = foo(error_prone_function(a,b,c))
    if result:
        do_success(result)
    else:
        do_failure(error)
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the exception object in `E`? You can just `return e`.

Comment: What if error_prone_function returns an exception object instead of raising an error?

Comment: Check `if isinstance(result, Exception)`. Are you expecting `error_prone_function` to *return* or *raise* an exception?

Comment: I wish to differentiate between returning and raising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a decorator function:

```
def catchall(f):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            return e
    return func
```

Now this can be used on all of your "dodgy" functions:

```
@catchall
def error_prone_function(...):
```

and caught elsewhere:

```
result = error_prone_function(...)
if isinstance(result, Exception):
    # deal with failure
else:
    # success!
```

However, it is generally better to handle *specific* errors than the general case "something has gone wrong"; you should really figure out why each routine is failing and install localised error handling to manage it.

Comment: Well, the idea is that I would run a bunch of error_prone_functions in parallel and then collect all the results as a list. Then I would go through each result and handle the situation depending on the type of error received.

Comment: My point is that it might be better to make `error_prone_function` *less* error prone by introducing error handling within it, where you are more likely to be able to do something sensible about whatever has gone wrong!

Comment: More generally, I am wishing to return success/failure, it happens that most of my failures are just exceptions so the pattern of returning errors occurs frequently.

Answer (score 1):

you can also return an exception and the real value. Python allows to return multiple values. You can use the first value for the result and the second value for the error.
If there is no error, it is a success:

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    try:
        return error_prone_function(a,b,c), None
    except Exception as e:
        return None, e

def bar():
    result, error = foo(1,2,3)
    # did an error happen
    if error is None:
        do_failure(error)
    else:
        do_success(result)
```

Here is the decorator for this solution

```
def catchall(f):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs), None
        except Exception as e:
            return None, e
    return func
```

And then you can call

```
def bar():
    result, error = catchall(foo)(1,2,3)
    # did an error happen
    if error is None:
        do_failure(error)
    else:
        do_success(result)
```

Comment: This is better, however I would ideally like to get rid of having to repeat foo for every instance of error_prone_function...

Comment: what do you mean by repeat foo?

Comment: It should be `if error is None:`, but neat otherwise!

Comment: @Michael_Scharf I mean I don't want to have a version of foo for every version of error_prone_function.

Comment: you could use a decorator function to wrap any function foo, as jonrsharpe usggested

Comment: @Michael_Scharf Yes, I am looking into it.